# GetById Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, api

> Hola, buenas noches. Estoy desarrollando una API mediante node JS en
>   la cual mi finalidad es obtener los discos seleccionados de acuerdo al
>   artista en específico.
>
> Sucede que tengo mi siguiente JSON y me gustaría poder obtener un
>   nuevo json de acuerdo al Id de un Artista, por ejemplo, si deseo
>   buscar el artista número uno el tercer resultado debería de omitirse y
>   así sucesivamente. Estoy utilizando nodeJS y quiero consumirlo a
>   manera de GET pasando por parámetro en la URL el Id a buscar. Muchas
>   gracias

```
    [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "Favourite Worst Nightmare",
    "year": "2007",
    "imagen": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/6e/6e/d4/mzi.hozudery.jpg/600x600bf.png",
    "idArtista": "1",
    "tracklist": [
      {
        "song": "Brianstorm",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uR3bNrIg9eE"
      },
      {
        "song": "Teddy Picker",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hl2lxaNjQOI"
      },
      {
        "song": "505",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNZCXzbj6Ds"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "nombre": "Whatever People Say I Am, That's What I'm Not",
    "year": "2006",
    "imagen": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Features/9a/68/e6/dj.npwkgmai.jpg/600x600bf.png",
    "idArtista": "1",
    "tracklist": [
      {
        "song": "The View from the Afternoon",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_N9jJwN1gE"
      },
      {
        "song": "Dancing Shoes",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYnUb1xDQ74"
      },
      {
        "song": "A Certain Romance",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQYLf2-vkC8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "nombre": "Innespeaker",
    "year": "2010",
    "imagen": "https://media.pitchfork.com/photos/5929a9e913d197565213993e/1:1/w_600/7ea586f7.jpg",
    "idArtista": "12",
    "tracklist": [
      {
        "song": "It's Not Meant to Be",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeZt5IGJ1T8"
      },
      {
        "song": "Alter Ego",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iErjaKTX_3w"
      },
      {
        "song": "Lucidity",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFe4lfueUdk"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

YA LO RESOLVÍ, SALUDOS

```
  /*Get ById*/

router.get('/:id?',(req,res) =>{
    const idArt = req.params;
    const newTracks = _.where(tracks, {idArtista : idArt.id});
    res.json(newTracks);
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Estoy haciendo uso de 'underscore'

Comment: Necesito convertir esto { id: '1' } en esto "1"

Comment: ¡ Genial que lo resolvieras ! ¿ Porqué no publicas una respuesta, que sirva de ayuda para futuros usuarios en tu misma situación ?

Comment: Por favor, no debes editar la pregunta y poner que lo resolviste. si es asi, Agrega una respuesta (esta bien visto contestar tu propia pregunta) y acepta tu respuesta luego de 24 hs. Se espera encontrar la respuesta en el campo respuesta. Ademas, mira [answer] para que tu respuesta sea completa

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la versión *underscore* del método `Array.map( )`:

```
router.get( '/:idArtista', ( req, res ) => {
  const idArt = req.params;
  const newTracks = _.map( _.where(tracks, { idArtista : idArt} ), function( val ) { return val.id; } );
  res.json(newTracks);
} );
```

Eso te devolverá un *array* de números, 1 por cada resultado, siendo dicho número el `id` del elemento.

Observa que **no tenemos en cuenta** la ausencia de resultados ... deberías comprobar esa eventualidad.